# Delimiters \left( and \right) do not work (fourier and teubner)

Tags: brackets, fourier

Sorry i posted a totally useless long post. I reproduced now the very same issue thanx to the comments of daleif. Here it is:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[polutonikogreek, italian,english]{babel}


\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{teubner}


\begin{document}


\begin{equation}\label{taus}
\tau_e=\left(\frac{N_r\sigma_e}{v_{th}}\right)^{-1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) This can easily be put into a single MWE (replace `\LoadClass` by `\documentclass` (2) Unrelated, you should never use `fancyhdr` with `memoir`, the classes own pagestyle system is much much more integrated into the class.

Comment: The class is loading both `fourier` and `mathpazo` this is well know to cause issues, if I remove `fourier` the fences work again. Just `mathpazo` is not enough

Comment: `teubner` and `fourier` does not seem to like each other. There are many things in this template that we generally do not recommend.

Comment: Thank you i was lost in finding the conflict but now you pointed out the two packages in conflict the MWE was reduced to the bone as you suggested. A sub-problem is now that the two packages behave differently if called in reversed order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The packages `teubner` and `fourier` don't cooperate well.
2. Never load two packages that define math fonts: either `mathpazo` (for Palatino) or `fourier` (for Utopia).

Next, loading `teubner` after `fourier` *seems* to fix the issues, but it doesn't.

Indeed, your formula becomes

[image]

and you see that `\left` and `\right` don't do their job.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[polutonikogreek, italian, english]{babel}

\usepackage{teubner}
\let\teubnerbreve\breve
\let\breve\relax
\usepackage{fourier}
\let\mbreve\breve
\let\breve\teubnerbreve

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{taus}
\tau_e=\left(\frac{N_r\sigma_e}{v_{th}}\right)^{-1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

If you don't plan to use `\breve` as a math accent it could be simplified, but it's better to have an alias `\mbreve` available. The code will redefine `\breve` as `teubner` does.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanx to the incredibly quick answer of daleif i found that the conflict is between teubner and fourier packages. But the issue is not commutative. This order of package call will compile but with the brackets issue reported:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[polutonikogreek, italian, english]{babel}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{teubner}


\begin{document}


\begin{equation}\label{taus}
\tau_e=\left(\frac{N_r\sigma_e}{v_{th}}\right)^{-1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

If we invert the order in which the packages are called it won't compile:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[polutonikogreek, italian, english]{babel}



\usepackage{teubner}

\usepackage{fourier}


\begin{document}


\begin{equation}\label{taus}
\tau_e=\left(\frac{N_r\sigma_e}{v_{th}}\right)^{-1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

giving an error because in fourier style command \breve finds an already defined one.

The issue is now solved by removing one of the two packages.